# Change the Exchange Online display name without changing the user display name in MS365

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, microsoft-365

A client who uses Exchange Online asked me today to change the name his recipients see when he sends an email. Instead of just displaying the first and last name, the company name should also become part of the display name, so it should look something like "First Last (Company)".

From what I've seen, the Exchange Display Name and the MS 365 Display Name are identical, so it's not possible to change one without changing the other. Which means that if I change the display name, it will also change it for Teams, for OneDrive, and any other service one may use, even in the Azure AD I assume.

- Is my understanding right and does the display name for email have to be equal the display name in MS 365?
- Is there a reason why we should refrain from making these changes to the display name, can we mess anything up by doing so?
- Is there another, better way I'm not seeing to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my exchange online lab, you could open admin center, go to the Users then go to Active users page.Select the user's name, and then on the Account tab select  Manage contact information.In the Display name box, type a new name for the person, and then select Save. Here are some testing screenshots for you:[image][image][image][image]

For more details: [Change a user's display name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/change-a-user-name-and-email-address?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fchange-a-user-name-and-email-address-in-office-365-fb5ac074-e203-4e1f-9843-b9d1a3e03297&view=o365-worldwide#change-a-users-display-name)

Comment: Hi Joy, I appreciate you took the time to write something but it's not an answer to my question(s).

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes, you can not change display name only when you send mails.